# calculation inside the grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to calculate inside the grid,multiple of 2 textBox values, key-press or keyup event.
can u provide me some javascript for this. I use the following code it does not work for me
javascript

```
var a = document.getElementById(txtlabchrgsNooflab);
    var b = document.getElementById(txtlabchrgsTotalCost);
    txtlabchrgsTotalCost=a*b;
```

Comment: `txtlabchrgsTotalCost=parseDouble(a.value())*parseDouble(b.value());`?

Comment: hi @mshsayem...i am getting this error Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'txtlabchrgsNooflab' is undefined

Comment: What are txtlabchrgsNooflab and txtlabchrgsTotalCost?  Are these variables defined elsewhere?  Or are they the ids of the elements on the page?  If they are ids, you'll need to put them in quotes, i.e. `getElementById("txtlabchrgsNooflab")`.

Comment: var a = document.getElementById("txtlabchrgsNooflab");
    var b = document.getElementById("txtlabchrgsCostperlab");
    txtlabchrgsTotalCost = parseDouble(a.value()) * (b.value());                                      i called in onkeyup for txtlabchrgscostperlab..but i get the following error:Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "inside the grid" - is that a particularly relevant aspect to this question?  And when something "does not work", you should give the error message or unexpected output if you want people to be able to work out *why*.

Comment: @user Do you understand that "object is null or undefined" message?  If so, it is straightforward to work out what is going wrong.  Why are your element references undefined?

Comment: i have a grid with 5 txtbox and 1 btn...if i entering the txtbox value, it automatically multiply txt3 and txt4 and result in txt5, wen i keyup on txt4...and i click btn to save on database-@AndrzejDoyle

Answer (score 2):

Firstly - if you want to multiply two things together, they're going to have to be numbers.

At the moment your `a` and `b` variables are simply the *HTML elements* you've identified, and you can't multiply those together.  (Though pay attention to Carl's comment; you may need to quote `txtlabchrgsNooflab` if this is meant to be a literal string and not a variable name.)

So you need to get the value of these elements, as a numeric datatype.  Getting the value should be as simple as calling `.value()` for text inputs; however, this returns a string.  This *may* get automatically coerced to a numeric type as required, but I would be happier (and think it's clearer) to call `parseFloat` on it definitively.

Once you have your two floats, you can merrily multiply them.  So your code should look something like the following:

```
var elemA = document.getElementById(txtlabchrgsNooflab);
var elemB = document.getElementById(txtlabchrgsTotalCost);
var a = parseFloat(elemA.value());
var b = parseFloat(elemB.value());

txtlabchrgsTotalCost = a * b;
```

---

OK, so using this above code results in:

> error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

What can we infer from this error message?  Well, that the runtime wasn't able to compute `value` because the thing it was being called on was null or undefined.

If you look at the code, it's clear which variable(s) might be null or undefined - and you should be able to inspect your HTML to see why this is, and make the required corrections.

Comment: var elemA = document.getElementById("txtlabchrgsNooflab");
var elemB = document.getElementById("txtlabchrgsTotalCost");
var a = parseFloat(elemA.value());
var b = parseFloat(elemB.value());

txtlabchrgsTotalCost = a * b;   i used , but its the error  Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

Comment: @user I've updated my answer based on your comment.  It looks like your code snippet has some very simple problems beyond the bounds of what you've posted.

Comment: but these txtbox r in footer template of grid...so it doesnt identify ah?

Comment: @user I'm sorry, I didn't understand that.  Could you rephrase it?

Comment: i kept the textbox in footer template in gridview, not in item template and edititemtemplate... so the error coming for this reason?

Comment: @user I have no idea what those templates are, they're presumably some artifact of the CMS you're using.  But in any case it shouldn't matter - the only relevant question is, **is there an element in the HTML output with the required ID**?  Or in other words, why is `document.getElementById` returning null?  Only you can answer that, because only you are controlling the HTML markup.

Comment: As Andrzej says, the big question is "is there an element in the HTML output with the required ID".  If you are using Webforms, remember that ASP.Net doesn't always render the ids in the markup the same as the control ids in the aspx, as it will prefix them with whatever naming containers are relevant. (I.e. txtlabchrgsNooflab could actually be grid1_txtlabchrgsNooflab.)  View the source of your rendered page and see what's actually been rendered.